# How does a recursive method count without a counter?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am writing methods for a binary search tree and am having trouble understanding the basics of recursion. I found a method that checks for the size of the binary search tree and I see how it it going through each element of the tree, but I don't understand how it is counting the size exactly. Can someone please explain this to me?

Here is the method:

```
unsigned long BST::sizeHelper(BSTNode* r){
    if (r == NULL){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (sizeHelper(r->left) + sizeHelper(r->right) + 1); //+1 for the root
    }
}
```

I see the return statement, but I don't see any indication of how it is counting the elements as it goes through them.

Comment: What do you think `+ 1` is doing there?

Comment: @n.m. I think OP understands that *something* is being incremented; I expect the confusion arises from the fact that there's no single variable representing the "current count" anywhere. Right, Xerunix?

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I actually though +1 was adding the root because the subtrees wouldn't include that, but now I realize that it is returning +1 to the recursive method that called it. Thank you so much. You too Kyle. I didn't realize that the return keyword returned a value to the method that called it...or at least wasn't thinking about it recursively.

Comment: You have already described correctly how it works. Compute the right hand subtree size, compute the left hand subtree size, add them up, add 1. Why do you think you need to keep track of any additional information, or that there's a hidden counter somewhere? Perhaps you should write yourself a recursive factorial function (one that stores all intermediate results in named variables) and run through it with a debugger.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't understand how it worked until after you made me question what the +1 did. I thought it was just counting the root node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon each return, the method adds **at least** one to the total size. 
For example, consider the following tree:

[image]
(I'm bad at drawing, so I stole one online)

Steps are as follow:

1. Start from A, `return size(B) + size(C) + 1`.
2. For B, `return size(D) + 0 + 1`. (0 because B has no right child, i.e. NULL)
3. For D, `return 0 + 0 + 1`. size(D) = 1.
4. Now going back, size(B) = 1 + 1 = 2.
5. For C, `return size(E) + size(F) + 1`.
6. Similar to D, size(E) = size(F) = 1.
7. Going back again, size(C) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3.
8. Finally, size(A) = 2 + 3 + 1 = 6.